# NLog Custom Target for JSNLog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I am currently developing an application which makes use of NLog for .NET logging and JSNLog to send logs from Javascript to NLog for logging. These logs are stored in a SQL database.

The SQL Database has several columns for NLog such as Message, StackTrace, InnerException and AdditionalInfo. However when I log something from JSNLog like so

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
    JL("databaseLogger").fatalException({
        "msg": "Uncaught Exception",
        "errorMsg": errorMsg, "url": url,
        "line number": lineNumber, "column": column
    }, errorObj);

    return false;
}
```

It is simply interpreted by NLog as a simple string log and not an error, so it just adds this giant JSON string to the AdditionalInfo column, and leaves the Message, StackTrace and InnerException columns blank. This makes reading the logs much harder.

I'd like to be able to parse this JSON sent by the JSNLog call and send it to the appropriate NLog variable, i.e:

```
JL("databaseLogger").fatalException({
    "Message": "Uncaught Exception",
    "InnerException": errorMsg,
}, errorObj);
```

would result in the Message and InnerException columns containing the data sent in the JSON. The parsing is not an issue as I know how to do that, but I am not sure how to intercept the call to NLog so I can parse the JSON before sending it onto NLog correctly.

I've looked into writing a [custom NLog target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target) which doesn't seem to hard, but I am not sure how to then pass my parsed JSON to Nlog correctly?

---

EDIT #1: Updated NLog.config for @Julian
Here is my new NLog.config but the Log from the new `Write` function does not get passed to the `database` target.

```
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="ParseJsonWrapper"
        name="JSONParser">
      <target name="database"
         xsi:type="Database"
         connectionStringName="ErrorLog"
         commandText="exec dbo.InsertLog
                            @level,
                            @callSite,
                            @type,
                            @message,
                            @stackTrace,
                            @innerException,
                            @additionalInfo">
        <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite}" />
        <parameter name="@type" layout="${exception:format=type}" />
        <parameter name="@message" layout="${exception:format=message}" />
        <parameter name="@stackTrace" layout="${exception:format=stackTrace}" />
        <parameter name="@innerException"
                    layout="${exception:format=:innerFormat=ShortType,Message,Method:MaxInnerExceptionLevel=1:InnerExceptionSeparator=}" />
        <parameter name="@additionalInfo" layout="${message}" />
      </target>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger levels="Trace,Info,Debug,Error,Warn,Fatal" name="JSLogger" writeTo="JSONParser"/>
  </rules>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's a good solution to create a TargetWrapper so you could combine it with other targets.

The config will looks like this:

```xml
  <target xsi:type="ParseJsonWrapper"
          name="myWrapper">
    <target xsi:type="File" ...target properties... />
  </target>
```

The code needed for this: inherit from `WrapperTargetBase` and override `Write`. e.g.

```
using System;
using NLog.Common;
/// <summary>
/// Limits the number of messages written per timespan to the wrapped target.
/// </summary>
[Target("ParseJsonWrapper", IsWrapper = true)]
public class ParseJsonWrapper : WrapperTargetBase
{
    protected override void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var json = logEvent.LogEvent.Message;
        // parse json

        // update log event
        logEvent.LogEvent.Exception = new Exception("something");

        // write to wrapped target
        WrappedTarget.WriteAsyncLogEvent(logEvent)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register your wrapper ([see here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component)) and update your config to write to the wrapper instead of the wrapped target.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I've registered my Wrapper and I can see the Message getting passed to my custom `Write` function, however once I change the `LogEvent.Exception` to use the data from the JSON, the `write` function just ends and the new Log is never passed to my `target` inside the `wrapper`. Is there something I am missing? I've updated the OP to include my new `NLog.config`.

Comment: oops, stripped too much from the example. You need to call `WrappedTarget.WriteAsyncLogEvent(logEvent)`, I have updated the example

Comment: For a working example, see also here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Targets/Wrappers/LimitingTargetWrapper.cs

Comment: Excellent, the updated example works great! I still have a few questions though. I can change the `Exception Type` by writing a custom exception Class, but I am unsure how to set the `Call Site` and `Stack Trace` variables. I noticed that there is a `SetStackTrace` function but this only takes a .NET StackTrace parameter and my stack is coming from Javascript in a string. I'd like to be able to set the `CallSite` to a string too. Thanks!

Comment: Are NLog properties an option? See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer

Comment: I'm guessing that stacktrace comes the exception, so your custom exception class can just override the virtual Exception.StackTrace property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx (For callsite then it should probably be implemented as properties, like NLog should also have done from the start)

Comment: @Julian @Rolf Thank you both for your help! I created a Custom Property and used the `whenEmpty` property so that my custom callsite will only be used when the real callsite property is empty. I also overrode the `Exception.StackTrace` property so that it would return my StackTrace string.